# Локальная переменная в теле цикла

Tags: java, циклы, переменные, объявление

На различных специализированных интернет-ресурсах бытует множество мнений по этому вопросу. Порой эти мнения диаметрально отличаются друг от друга. К примеру, есть целый пласт практикующих специалистов, которые крайне не рекомендуют так делать (в основном из сообщества программистов, которые работают с языком C/C++). Другие же ратуют за то, чтобы переменные объявлялись настолько "локально", насколько это вообще возможно. Какая практика, на Ваш взгляд, является более оправданной?

Двигаемся дальше... Мне бы хотелось понять, что происходит со стеком, когда мы декларируем переменную в цикле. Правильно ли я понимаю, что после каждой пройденной итерации, те локальные переменные, которые были объявлены непосредственно в теле самого цикла, проходят через процесс удаления из стека (выполняется операция pop), а потом снова туда загружаются (это происходит уже в процессе новой итерации, в этом случае срабатывает операция push)? Не уверен, что это так, но на такие размышления меня навёл следующий тестовый код:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if(i == 1)
                System.out.println(j);
            int j = 0;
        }
    }
}

/*
    Compilation Errors Detected

    Line: 6
    cannot find symbol
      symbol:   variable j
      location: class Test
*/
```

Как мы можем видеть, компилятор указывает нам на то, что в пределах области видимости, в которой мы пытаемся получить доступ к нашей локальной переменной, собственно отсутствует переменная с таким идентификатором (хотя мы её уже объявляли в предыдущей итерации). Что меня ещё смущает так это то, что если взглянуть на байт-код в случае, если переменная будет указана вне цикла (но будет использоваться в нём) и аналогичный бинарный код для той ситуации, когда объявление проходило в цикле, то выяснится, что они абсолютно одинаковы!

Теперь ключевой вопрос. Учитывая всё вышенаписанное, что же происходит на самом деле?

Comment: 1) Вы пишите на Java, зачем вы слушаете тех кто пишет на си\си++? это совершенно разные ЯП с разным поведением с разными подкапотными действиями.
2) Что же происходит на самом деле - ровно то что вы видите в байт коде.
3) Ну и теперь более оправданным является использование **подходящих переменных под текущие нужды**. если вам нужна локальная переменная - используйте локальную, нужна глобальная - используйте глобальную.

Comment: А со стеком какие манипуляции выполняются? Неужели переменная загружается туда лишь единожды?

Comment: 4) Хитрости конечно есть всегда, но вам о них рано задумываться, сначала надо выучить от и до как именно работает ваш ЯП, его оптимизатор, внутренние структуры, и только после вы сможете понять трюки по оптимизации.

Comment: Отвечаю на ваш комментарий, вам это знать сейчас не нужно, что изменит это знание для вас сейчас? вы сможете правильно это использовать? вы хорошо знаете архитектуру ВМ Java?... зы. все мои советы - из разряда общих, я не являюсь программистом на Java, и уж тем более не знаю ее поднаготную. И да, пролью вам свет немного - как именно будет хранится переменная очень сильно зависит от того как она будет использована, современные ЯП очень хорошо умеют оптимизировать код

Comment: Зачем это знать? Хочу удовлетворить своё любопытство! Уж простите, такой я человек по своей природе. Если возник какой-то вопрос в голове и я не могу найти на него ответ, то порой даже заснуть не могу!)

Comment: Хотите удовлетворить любопытство - берите книжку по поднаготной Java и изучайте архитектуру этой ВМ, тогда вы сможете понимать как именно это происходит под капотом. Сейчас вам действительно нужно знать лишь то что Java лучше вас знает как именно нужно хранить переменную =) И совет - если вы хотите быть программистом - пусть ближайшее время это так и остается. Сейчас, когда ресурсы огромны, за битами гонятся не принято.

Comment: "_в пределах области видимости, в которой мы пытаемся получить доступ к нашей локальной переменной, собственно отсутствует переменная с таким идентификатором (хотя мы её уже объявляли в предыдущей итерации)_" - это не так. Компилятор не смотрит на итерации и прочие if-ы. Компилятор видит использование переменной до её объявления  и ожидаемо сообщает об этом.

Comment: @Эникейщик Примерно так и понял. А в стеке что в это время творится?

Comment: в Java принято максимально ограничивать область видимости, то что принято в С++, должно волновать тех, кто разрабатывает на C++, но никак не разработчика Java.

Answer (score 0):

Память под стек выделяется один раз. Компилятор расчитывает максимально необходимую память и выделяет столько сколько надо.

```
void foo() {
   if(condition1) {
       int i = 1;
   }
   if(condition2) {
       int j = 2;
   }
}
```

В этом примере на стеке будет выделена память только для одной переменной.

Операция `pop` (точнее ее аналог) вызывается только один раз при выходе из метода.

Ваш пример с ошибкой компиляции объясняется тем что компилятор гарантирует то что локальные переменные будут проинициализированны.

Comment: То есть, если мы объявляем переменную в цикле, то выделение памяти под неё произойдёт всего 1 раз?

Comment: @Lexoid Именно так. Память на стеке выделяется один раз для вызова функции.